# Check if value exists in nested object MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While I'm following a course and practicing using NodeJS and MongoDB, I found an obstacle that could be worked on in a better way, and I need your help to figure out how I could do that

Model `Post.js`:

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  likes: [
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
      },
    },
  ],
  comment: [
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

And now the `X User` would `like` a post of `Y User`, here is my major problem, how I could check if `X User`liked the post or still not yet
here is the logic I wrote

```
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.post_id);
    if (post.likes.filter((x) => x.user == req.user.id).length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'You already like this post' });
    }
    const newLike = {
      user: req.user.id,
    };
    post.likes.unshift(newLike);
    await post.save();
```

So as you see here I'm checking the length of objects in the likes array, I believe there is better way than getting all objects and then getting the length, such as using `findOne` or `exists` for checking if there one object then return `true` rather than searching among all objects in the array, but unfortunately, after using them it keeps show me different types of error such as `it's not a function` or `can't using on object`

also in another hand in `unlike` logic, I tried to `$pull` the like as to be unliked, here is the code I wrote

```
    await post.likes.findOneAndUpdate({ $pull: { _id: req.user.id } }, { new: true });
```

but unfortunately, it keeps showing me an error message  `TypeError: post.likes.findOneAndUpdate is not a functions`, also I tried to use other functions such `deleteOne` , or `update` but all keep showing me the same error, IDK why, but I believe because I'm using it on an object rather than a collection

so could you make this code better to getting better based on your experience

Thanks all

Comment: btw insted of filter you can use some `if (post.likes.some((x) => x.user == req.user.id))` it will return true at least 1 found

Comment: Good added, I tried it's working perfectly, thank you for this info